# Passing text info to a WPF "balloon" window

Tags: wpf, window

I want to be able to launch a "balloon"-type window when errors happen in my command line apps that I run in a batch.  I'm thinking of creating a WPF executable, and passing it the message to be displayed on its command line.

Will I be able to pass in Unicode characters on its command line?

Can anyone suggest a different approach of passing the text to be displayed to a WPF window in an external executable/DLL?

[request for more detail]

Essentially I'm looking for an easy way to launch a window with some message, and that message will come executables that don't have a UI (windows service, ommand line tool).  I was thinking of calling a WPF app with the message on the command line, like this: 
NotificationBalloon.exe "this is the message to display"
but that wouldn't support unicode characters.  I'm looking for a better way to pass the message to NotificationBalloon.exe

Comment: Could you go in more detail with your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up passing the UTF-16 values on the command line and converting it to a string inside my main() function.  For example:

NotifWindow.exe 00480065006c006c006f0021
will print out "Hello!"

Answer (score 1):

You can have your `NotificationBalloon.exe` read the unicode string from standard input on execution, and use input redirection when spawning it:

```
public void Foo()
{
    SpawnBalloon("Whatever you want, this can be UNICODE as well.");
}

private void SpawnBalloon(string message)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("NotificationBalloon.exe")
    {
        RedirectStandardInput = true
    };
    var process = Process.Start(psi);
    process.StandardInput.Write(message);
    process.StandardInput.Flush(); // Might not be necessary if AutoFlush is true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass unicode characters on the command line without the risk of them being mangled. Pass it a path to a temp file which contains the text (or if you want to get fancy, you could use pipes)